# He will give money

Tags: scams, money-transfer

There's this man I met in facebook, saying that he will give me money. He's sending pictures of his house, garden, relatives. How do I know if this is a scam? He said he lives in Kiama, Australia.

Comment: He asks for my Name 
Street Address
Province
City and zip code
Email address or phone number so that he can send money via moneygram

Comment: People generally don't give away money to people they don't even know - unless they expect something in return.

Comment: Has he asked you to do anything with the money? Because this could be the beginning to scamming schemes we've seen plenty of on this side. Send the money elsewhere, he reverses the transaction and you're out of your money.

Comment: @Scorch91 Chances are that he wants to build some trust first...

Comment: Hello update; he sent some pictures in this bank transfer idk I already refused. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 15):

You know this is a scam because he's contacted you out of the blue offering money. The pictures probably aren't his and the money he's offering you is definitely not his (it's either unclean money that needs an innocent party to launder it, or it's someone else's money / account etc. that he needs a method to get at without traceability back to him). There are many many questions on here from people who have got further down this route with these kinds of people - browse the "scams" tag for more. Well done for spotting that something isn't quite right, and coming here to ask about it - now block him, delete the messages and move on.